# Trying to create slice of type MovingAvarage

Tags: go, slice, moving-average

I am using the RobinUS2/golang-moving-average library to compute moving avarages, but I am unable to assembe a slice of these avarages to compute MA for multiple variables.

```
ma := []movingaverage.MovingAverage{}
    ma[0] = movingaverage.New(15)
    ma[0].Add(3.14)
```

What could be wrong? I get an index out of range error. Thanks!

Comment: `ma` has a length of 0, so you can't index anything. Is `ma` supposed to have a fixed number of values?

Comment: yes, I know the length of ma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either pre-size the slice with

```
ma := make(movingaverage.MovingAverage, 5)
```

Which gives a slice of capacity 5 and length 5 with each entry set to the zero value

Better though to initialise it as you did but then to add new entries with

```
ma = append(ma, movingaverage.New(15))
```

If you know how big your eventual slice will be you can pre-allocate the underlying array with

```
ma := make(movingaverage.MovingAverage, 0, 5)
```

which will give you a slice of length 0 but capacity 5 so you don't have to do repeated memory allocations and moves

Comment: You don't seed to set capacity of 5 with a length of 5, it's implied.

Comment: Thank you, I have overlooked it.

Comment: Using `append` causes unnecessary allocations and copy operations. If the necessary size is known beforehand, it is better to initialize the slice with the necessary capacity and set the individual slice index to the respective value.

Comment: Marcus and Jim, You're both right - I'll expand the answer to capture your comments